# Mondrian / Saiku - Aggregate tables not used by SqlTupleReader

Tags: performance, pentaho, mondrian, saiku, aggregates

We are trying to improve the **performance of a Saiku analytics server**. For this, we have created **aggregate tables at different granularities** so that Mondrian can make use of them and retrieve the results faster.

While analyzing the logs, we have discovered that the aggregate tables are **not being used by the SqlTupleReader class** of Mondrian. This class has the responsibility of creating the different combinations of the dimensions in a cube.

On the other hand, Mondrian is **using the aggregages successfully to retrieve data segments**.

After reviewing the code and some similar cases, we have found that Mondrian 4 lacks this feature, while other versions are doing it correctly.

We were wondering if there is **any version of Mondrian compatible with Saiku that supports aggregate tables to retrieve dimension tuples** and, if so, how could we use this version in our instalation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is the feedback I received from the Saiku team:

https://github.com/OSBI/saiku/issues/647

It seems that we won't be getting support for this feature, but we can use the workaround proposed in the thread.